Can I create another branch from one that's open from my main?
So I have a branch A open from my main/master branch. There's a different ticket from A that I need to work on, which overall like all tickets at the end gets merged into the master. Right now, I have one branch open from my main, which is A. Would it be possible to create a branch 'B' from A, do the work that I need to do on it, and then merge B into A? And then make sure to run a "git pull" command so my local A branch gets all remote changes? And once I'm done with A, merge that into my remote main branch, so the remote main branch gets both A and B's changes?

You asked on Reddit too without informing them about this question. Isn’t one place at a time enough?

This question is low quality. It is about creating branches, checking out and merging. A quick google search gives a much more sufficient answer.
Is there more context for as why this is confusing? Perhaps a nuance that isn’t quite making sense?

You might wanna read about branching in git: https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/19/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-6-branching-in-a-nutshell/

Yes, you can,
Follow the steps:

Ensure you are on branch A:
git checkout A


Create a new branch B from branch A:
git checkout -b B


Work on branch B:
Make your changes and commits on branch B until the task is completed.

Once the task is done, switch back to branch A:
git checkout A


Merge branch B into branch A:
git merge B


Push the changes to the remote repository
git push



